# Obtaining a raw pointer through an iterator with C++20

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20

Sometimes I used `&*it` to get a raw pointer from an iterator. But this doesn't always work when I'm using interator-debugging, consider getting a raw pointer of `&*myVec.end()`. AFAIK there's a templated C++20 function to get an address from an iterator, but I can't remember it anymore. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: [`std::to_address`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/to_address)?

Comment: @康桓瑋: One overload is for fancy pointers and not iterators and the other is for pointers.

Comment: Since C++20, there is `std::to_address()`.  Before C++20, you need to check that `it` is not an end iterator before evaluating `&*it`.

Comment: @Peter: to_address has two specializations, one for fancy pointers and one for normal pointers, but none for any iterator.

Comment: So what do you think is a fancy pointer?

Comment: @康桓瑋 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/pointer_traits/to_address it's actually described like that.

Comment: @BonitaMontero - Iterators have characteristics/traits associated with "fancy pointers".

Comment: @alagner: Alanger, I read that and from there you can get a link which describes that a fancy-pointer shares a lot of properties with normal pointers and iterators, but are used for totally different purposes.

Comment: @BonitaMontero: "*fancy pointers and not iterators*" Contiguos iterators *are* "fancy pointers".

Answer (score 3):

For any iterator `i` which [is a `contiguous_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/contiguous_iterator), the expression `to_address(i)` shall result in a pointer to a location in the range of the iterator, or a past-the-end pointer if it is the past-the-end iterator of the range. This can be provided via a specialization of `pointer_traits<I>` for the iterator type `I`, but for many iterators, calling `operator->()` is adequate to the task.

This is only supported for contiguous iterators because... well, it doesn't make much sense otherwise. Assuming we're talking about a C++20 iterator that is *not* a proxy iterator (ie: `reference` is exactly `value_type&`), it is possible to get a pointer to the underlying value. But there is no requirement that the *end* iterator give you a pointer that is in any way meaningful.

This is only meaningful for contiguous iterators, because contiguous iterators have to point to an actual C++ array of `value_type`s. As such, there is a pointer which is a past-the-end pointer to that array. Even if you could extract some kind of pointer from the end iterator of a non-contiguous iterator, it wouldn't be meaningful because non-contiguous iterators don't (necessarily) point to arrays.

So if you're working with a non-contiguous iterator, just use `&*i`. It won't work on non-dereferenceable iterators, but *nothing* could work on those, since there's no pointer it could return.

Comment: Read: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/to_address - to_address is for usual poitners or fancy-pointers, but not iterators. In the latter article the word iterator is non-existing.

Comment: @BonitaMontero: And read the link I gave. A type cannot be a `contiguous_iterator` unless it provides access to `to_address`. A `vector<T>::iterator` is a `contiguous_iterator`, therefore it must provide this. It could be provided via a `pointer_traits` overload or with an explicit specialization of `std::to_address`. The standard does not care which; it only cares that `to_address(i)` shall be legitimate code and result in a pointer.

Comment: @BonitaMontero: The `to_address` documentation is not going to list any overloads of the template, because those are implementation details for the contiguous_iterators that provide them. The code `to_address(i)` simply must be legitimate for contiguous_iterators, period.

Comment: Then show me the documentation on en.cppreference.com for vector or the like.

Comment: @BonitaMontero: You do know that cppreference is not the C++ standard right? Because the C++ standard is very clear that `vector<T>` is a [contiguous container](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/vector#overview-2), which [must have `contiguous_iterator`s](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/container.requirements.general#13), which [are defined as outlined](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/iterator.concept.contiguous). That cppreferene hasn't been fully updated to C++20 is beyond my control.